# nhibernate delete multiple records by list of id's with CreateQuery

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sql-server-ce

I am trying to delete multiple records from TABLE A that exits in list of ids in TABLE B as follows:

```
List<ulong> ids = new List<ulong> {1, 2};

string deleteQuery = string.Format(
                @"DELETE FROM TABLE_A WHERE EXISTS 
                (SELECT id FROM TABLE_B WHERE checkpoint_id IN :idList)");

Session.CreateQuery(deleteQuery).SetParameterList("idList", ids).ExecuteUpdate();
```

I get the following Exception:

```
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException: Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. near line 2, column 100
```

If I put the list hardcoded [IN (1,2)] it works.
What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem:

I needed an extra **brackets** arround the :idList.

```
string deleteQuery = string.Format(
            @"DELETE FROM TABLE_A WHERE EXISTS 
            (SELECT id FROM TABLE_B WHERE checkpoint_id IN (:idList))");
```